# Creating a new Thread error "constructor test in class test cannot be applied to given types"

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a new thread for the game I'm making but it keeps giving me this error

```
Error: constructor test in class test cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Heres what is imported

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*; 
import java.util.*;
```

Here is what I'm trying to make a thread

```
>public class test extends JPanel implements Runnable
>{
>...<snip>...
 > Random generator = new Random();
>...<snip>...
>    try
>    {
>      Thread.sleep(100);
>    }catch(Exception e)
>    {
>      e.printStackTrace();
>    }
>  public static void main(String args[])
>  {
>...<snip>...
>  }
>}
```

And I'm using this to create thread

```
Thread test1 = new Thread(new test("one"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the "test" class has no constructor that takes just a String. Try putting the line "test testvar = new test("one")" right before the line where you're creating the Thread. You should see the same error. Add the constructor to your class.

You should also rename the class to start with an uppercase letter. This is the convention in Java.

Comment: Thanks, but two quick question it gave me the same error should happen right? and what would be an example of a constructor.(forgive me I'm new to programing)

Comment: It should give you the same error, but on the new line of code. For constructors I googled "java constructor tutorial" and found http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html .